# How to view a crystal report from a VS2017 C++ application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS2017 C++ application that currently includes a large number of Crystal reports which are viewed through an external exe file built using the Crystal Reports XI developer edition.  This included a C++ class, `CCrystalReportViewer11`, which can be used to view and access reports from a Visual studio 2008 C++ application.  I have installed the latest VS2017 Crystal reports IDE version and can view and edit my reports in the IDE, but can't find out how to run them from my application.  Searching the SAP doesn't bring up anything more recent than 2008, [results page](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+for+.NET+SDK+Samples).

**Edit:**  More digging suggests that this may not be possible in unmanaged C++, links below;

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/892008
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3276392

I'll look at wrapping the managed C++ app in the short term